# Average Excel Columns

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I am trying to average out values within a column at a certain range. I tried listing out the range as a tuple then for looping to be able to get the cell value. I then created a variable for the average but get the error 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

```
range1 = ws["A2":"A6]
for cell in range1:
    for x in cell:
        average = sum(x.value)/len(x.value)
        print(average)
```

Comment: `for x in cell` is iterating through the contents of the cell, which in your case is a float. Floats cannot be iterated, if you had a string in the cell it would return each character, you need to remove that loop.

Comment: Also `len(float)` is problematic as well, if you need the length of it you need to convert it to a string, though that won't give you an average, you would need to count the number of values and divide the sum by that, assuming you want the mean.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to sum up the values within the range of interest. I've removed the for loop now focusing on the average. Now it's saying unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will get you the mean of the cells.

```
import openpyxl as op

def main():
    wb = op.load_workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\####\\Desktop\\SO nonsense\\Book1.xlsm')
    
    range1 = wb['Sheet1']['A2:A6']
    cellsum = 0
    for i, cell in enumerate(range1, 1): 
        print(i)
        cellsum += cell[0].value
        
    print(cellsum / i)
main()
```

Comment: This is a little complicated and you should avoid creating your own counters if possible. Also, there is no need to alias the library name here, simply import the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

Python and the Openpyxl API makes this kind of thing very easy.

```py
rows = ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=6, max_col=1, values_only=True)
values = [row[0] for row in rows]
avg = sum(values) / len(values)
```

But you should probably check that the cells contain numbers, otherwise you'll see an exception.